# Set logging level for mongodb java driver 3.0

Tags: java, mongodb, log4j2

I'm including the mongo java 3.0 driver in a plugin for an application that uses log4j2. I can't modify the log4j2.xml file, but I need to be able to set the logging level for the mongo driver.

This would have worked if it was using the native java logger:

```
Logger mongoLogger = Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver");
mongoLogger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```

But this won't affect log4j2.

I don't want to affect levels for all loggers, just the mongo one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [log4j2 JMX interface](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/jmx.html) to set the log level of a log4j2 logger, if this logger has been named in the configuration.

Comment: I can't set any configuration values in any file except the java. My application is a plugin and the log4j2 xml is already defined by the main application.